# How to edit an existing histogram (or any chart)?

Tags: r, histogram

I'm working through an R tutorial. Currently I'm making histograms. As the tutorial progresses it asks for changes to the already constructed histograms - add an xlab, add main etc etc.

That's fine except each time I have to create the histogram from scratch.

How does one edit existing rather than write out all the code again? Would it be a matter of making the histogram an object and just editing it each time? I tried that. Lets say I start with this:

```
hearthist <- hist(outcome[,11])
```

I then want to add an xlabel. I tried this with no joy:

```
hearthist (xlab="30-Day Death Rate")
```

Whats the best practice here? Do I need to recreate a fresh histogram each time I want to add a parameter?

Comment: Your best bet would be to use an IDE (a topic on that here somewhere) and rerun your code as you go along. Recycling code is part of the R paradigm.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No; base graphics use a pen on paper idiom; once you make a mark that is it until you get a new piece of paper.

So, use to learn the appropriate tools. In this case an R-aware editor that you can write your R code and pipe it into a running R instance. I use ESS with Emacs, but the kool kids use RStudio. Give the latter a go.

Even standard, plain old R has a history mechanism which allows you to scroll back through your commands and re-run them from the command line.

Or learn to use the appropriate R tools. `title()` allows you to **add** `xlab`, `ylab`, `main`, and `sub` to an existing plot.

Comment: Thats good to know about the history mechanism. Could you elaborate a little? Because when I try and scroll up in my window I'm unable to alter already run code

Comment: Forget your mouse; use the cursor keys on your keyboard.

Comment: Ha! Thats funny I never even knew - been on this course a week now. Thanks for the tip

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to build a scene. I mean you add further output to a basic plot.
I Think that the graphics package is not very flexible in terms of visually decoding the information of a plot.

I would use other R-graphics  pacakge like Lattice/ggplot2 based on the grid package which are more suitable for such manipulations.

here an example using ggplot2:

```
set.seed(1234)
df <- data.frame(cond = factor( rep(c("A","B"), each=200) ), 
                 rating = c(rnorm(200),rnorm(200, mean=.8)))
ggplot(df, aes(x=rating)) + geom_histogram(binwidth=.5)
```

Now I edit the xlab of the original scene:

```
last_plot()+xlab("30-Day Death Rate")
```